# is there any alternate for arraylist.remove(element) function?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview

my recycler view reloads with spinner value, selected data is stored in a global arraylist, and here is my recycler view code to do the selection and deselection. Selection and deselection works just fine, but when i **select and **cha**nge spinner value**, and then come to back original spinner value, where items are already selected, deselction happens, **but item is not removed from the global arraylist.** While debugging i found that cursor reaches there, but i dont know why .remove() isnt working. Is there any alternative for it or am i doing wrong? Is there anything i should know that why isnt the item removed.

.
.
.

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(val dataList:ArrayList<ModelClass>,val onItemClicked: (Int) -> Unit):RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

 object ob {
     val dataSelected = ArrayList<ModelClass>()
     val hm = HashMap<ModelClass,String>()


 }


 fun setData(listModel: List<ModelClass>) {
     dataList.clear()
     dataList.addAll(listModel)
     notifyDataSetChanged()

 }


 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
     val binding = ItemViewBinding.inflate(
         LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false
     )
     return ViewHolder(binding, parent.context)
 }


 @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

     holder.bindItems(dataList[position])

 }

 override fun getItemCount() = dataList.size

 inner class ViewHolder(
     val binding: ItemViewBinding,
     val context: Context
 ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

     var count=0
     @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
     fun restore() {


         for (i in 0 until ob.dataSelected.size) {
             for (j in 0 until dataList.size) {
                 if (ob.dataSelected[i].sku_code == (dataList[j]).sku_code) {
                     if (adapterPosition == j) {

                         itemView.isSelected = true
                         itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black)
                         count=count+1
                         println("****")

                     }

                 }

             }
         }

         if(!itemView.isSelected){

                 itemView.isSelected = false
                 itemView.setBackgroundResource(0)


         }
     }

     @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor", "ResourceType")
     fun bindItems(data: ModelClass) = with(binding) {


         binding.itemQuant.text = data.item_quant
         binding.itemName.text = data.item_name
         binding.mfgName.text = data.mfg
         binding.quantity.text = data.item_stock.toString()


         count=0

         restore()
         itemView.setOnClickListener {

            count += 1
             var isPresent:Int
             if (count%2 == 0){
                 isPresent=1
             }
             else
             {
                 isPresent=0
             }


             if (isPresent == 1) {
                 it.setBackgroundResource(0)  //works
                 ob.dataSelected.remove(dataList[adapterPosition]) //doesnt work if spinner value is changed and changed back. works while still on same screen.

             } else {
                 if (isPresent == 0) {
                     it.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black)


                     ob.dataSelected.add(dataList[adapterPosition])
                     
                }
                 // onItemClicked.invoke(adapterPosition)
             }

         }

     }
 }
```

}

Comment: On your method `setData`, you are adding the values to `dataList` and I can't see where else you are modifying that list. It always remains the same.

Comment: list is modified, when spinner value is changed, and rcv adapter is called with new data.

Comment: Are you calling `setData` again, or `notifyDataSetChanged()` from your view ?

Comment: i am using setdata to call rcv adapter from the fragment, so that everytime adapter is called it does that.

Comment: What I mean is, are you calling setData more than once? You need to call that each time you modify your list and pass the modified list. Or you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` whenever you modify the list in your fragment.

Comment: Hey Filip, I am using setdata() to load the data into recyclerview everytime its loaded. I am not changing recycler view data until I change spinner Value, and when i change spinner value I am calling setData again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's not being removed? Have you set a breakpoint and checked the contents of the array (or just logged it)? Because it looks like when you're binding a viewholder, you just check if the item is in `dataSelected`, and if it is you set the view's `selected` and `backgroundColor` values. It doesn't look like you change them back if it's **not** in `dataSelected`, so that *selected* appearance "sticks".

It looks like you're trying to reset them with this:

```
if(!itemView.isSelected){
    itemView.isSelected = false
    itemView.setBackgroundResource(0)
}
```

but that only works if `itemView.selected` hasn't been set to `true`, which it has if your item is in `dataSelected`. You need to do it like this:

```
 for (i in 0 until ob.dataSelected.size) {
     for (j in 0 until dataList.size) {
         // rolling multiple conditions into a single value makes it easier to do an if/else
         val selected = ob.dataSelected[i].sku_code == (dataList[j]).sku_code && adapterPosition == j
         if (selected) {
             itemView.isSelected = true
             itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black)
             count=count+1
             println("****")
         } else {
             itemView.isSelected = false
             itemView.setBackgroundResource(0)
         }

     }
 }
```

That way you're *always* updating the contents of the view holder to reflect the state of the current item. That's especially important in `RecyclerView`s, because the point of those is that the `ViewHolder`s get reused to display different items, and any `View` attributes you don't set when binding (e.g. colours, checkbox statuses) will just stay on whatever they were last set to when displaying some other item.

---

btw, you can simplify that looping situation by just checking if anything in `dataSelected` has the SKU you're looking for:

```
val itemSku = datalist[adapterPosition].sku_code
val selected = ob.dataSelected.any { it.sku_code == itemSku }
```

ideally you wouldn't be using `adapterPosition` to find the current item either - the item you're matching is passed in to `bindItems` (as `data`), you could just pass that to your `restore` function

---

**edit** if the items **aren't** being removed from `dataSelected`, at a guess it's because the object you're fetching from `dataList` "doesn't exist" in `dataSelected`. By "doesn't exist" I mean there isn't an object that `equals` the one you're trying to `remove`.

```
ob.dataSelected.remove(dataList[adapterPosition])
```

I'm assuming that might be the case because you're not doing straight object comparisons when you're checking if an item is in the selected array, you're specifically comparing their `sku_code` values instead

```
if (ob.dataSelected[i].sku_code == (dataList[j]).sku_code)
```

If you can't just do `if (obj.dataSelected[i] == dataList[j])`, then `remove` won't work either - it's the same check. So maybe you need to look into making those objects equal (e.g. using data classes if that works for what you're doing), or use `removeAll` with a predicate (`remove` only works with a specific item):

```
ob.dataSelected.removeAll { it.sku_code == dataList[adapterPosition].sku_code }
```

You'll still have the problem of the UI not being updated though, like the first part of the answer explains! So you might have two problems here

Comment: Hey, that worked like a charm, it had come to my understanding that its not removing because it couldnt find such element, everytime recycler view was loaded, the itemView had different value and thats why it was not getting deleted. I was still figuring out the way, and this worked like a charm. Also, my restore() function was working until I changed the spinner value 3-4 times, after that it had random selections(I was thinking to worry about that later). 

Anyways, you solved both of the problems, Thanks a ton!

Comment: @SyedAhad no worries!

Answer (score 0):

change this line

`ob.dataSelected.add(dataList[adapterPosition])`

to this

`ob.dataSelected.add(dataList[adapterPosition].copy)`

Don't forget to call notfiyDatasetChanged() after that

Comment: Hey siddharth, add is working fine, and datalist is an arraylist of type Modelclass, so .copy gives me an error. I have trouble in removing element from the list